# Spark accessing remote master

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to run my code in jupyter notebook locally, to access a spark cluster on my own server, but without success, so that's the code

I've tried this

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('SparkApp').setMaster('spark://X.X.X.123:7077')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

and this way

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://X.X.X.123:7077").getOrCreate()
```

I received this error [updated]

```
### Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
###: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

new error after open port 7077

```
21/11/23 20:39:32 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native- 
hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes 
where applicable
21/11/23 20:39:33 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed 
to connect to master 192.168.0.123:7077
```

with 'local' work normally

[image]

Comment: does `master("local")` work ?

Comment: yes, work normally @Steven

Comment: Does Spark process listen to `7077` at `192.168.0.123`?

Comment: @chenzhongpu What do you mean? the local machine and server this port was open